# Setup keycloak version 21.0.2 with postgresSQL using docker-compse

Tags: postgresql, docker-compose, keycloak

I am trying to do this but not able to find any proper documentation to help me this is the image that I am using in my docker-compose file quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:21.0.2.

Answer (score 1):

This is a sample docker-compose.yml on which I confirmed keycloak looks working well.

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:13.2
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: keycloak
      POSTGRES_USER: keycloak
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  keycloak:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:21.0.2
    command: start-dev
    environment:
      DB_VENDOR: POSTGRES
      DB_ADDR: postgres
      DB_DATABASE: keycloak
      DB_USER: keycloak
      DB_PASSWORD: password
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: admin
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: admin
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    depends_on:
      - postgres

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

Comment: Can you share mySQL/Keycloak V21's docker-compose.yml too?

Answer (score 0):

You can aslo use [bitnami/keycloak](https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/keycloak/) docker image. Below my `docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  postgresql:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/postgresql:11
    environment:
      # ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD is recommended only for development.
      - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
      - POSTGRESQL_USERNAME=bn_keycloak
      - POSTGRESQL_DATABASE=bitnami_keycloak
    volumes:
      - 'postgresql_data:/bitnami/postgresql'

  keycloak:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/keycloak:21
    restart: always
    environment:
      KEYCLOAK_DATABASE_VENDOR: postgresql
      KEYCLOAK_CREATE_ADMIN_USER: true
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_USER: admin
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: admin
      KEYCLOAK_MANAGEMENT_USER: manager
      KEYCLOAK_MANAGEMENT_PASSWORD: manager
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    depends_on:
      - postgresql
volumes:
  postgresql_data:
    driver: local
```